# Why are there gaps in my fibonacci sphere?

Tags: opengl, c, sphere

I recently took an interest in sphere topologies to find which one is the best. The most popular one seems to be the fibonacci sphere. So I went and did some research and found some C code online that generates a fibonacci sphere.
[image]

[image]

Obviously at the moment it doesn't look like a sphere, but when I normalize the vertices, it forms this
[image]

[image]

It does form a sphere, but as you can see, there are a bunch of gaps in the sphere.

This is the function that generates the sphere

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_POINTS 1000

void fibonacci_sphere(int samples, float points[][3]) {
/*
Generates points on a sphere using Fibonacci spiral sampling.

:param samples: Number of points to generate.
:type samples: int
:param points: Array to store generated points.
:type points: list of lists
:raises TypeError: If samples is not an integer or points is not a list of lists.
:return: None
*/

// Validate inputs
if (samples <= 0) {
    printf("Number of samples must be a positive integer.\n");
    return;
}
if (points == NULL) {
    printf("Points array cannot be NULL.\n");
    return;
}

// Calculate golden angle in radians
float phi = M_PI * (sqrtf(5.0) + 1.0);

// Generate points on sphere
for (int i = 0; i < samples; i++) {
    // Calculate y coordinate
    float y = 1.0 - ((float)i / (float)(samples - 1)) * 2.0;

    // Calculate radius at y
    float radius = sqrtf(1.0 - y * y);

    // Calculate golden angle increment
    float theta = phi * i;

    // Calculate x, y, and z coordinates of point
    float x = cosf(theta) * radius;
    float z = sinf(theta) * radius;

    // Store point in points array
    points[i][0] = x;
    points[i][1] = y;
    points[i][2] = z;
}

// Log number of points generated
printf("%d points generated on sphere.\n", samples);
}
```

And here is where I apply the function

```
float vertices[100][3];
fibonacci_sphere(100, vertices);

unsigned int vbo, vao;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);

glBindVertexArray(vao);

// upload vertex data to gpu
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices) * sizeof(double), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// position attribute
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

// normal attribute
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

// amount of tessellation to do per triangle
glPatchParameteri(GL_PATCH_VERTICES, 3);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glDrawArrays(GL_PATCHES, 0, 100);
```

Here are my tessellation shaders

```
#version 450 core
// tessellation control
// specify control points per output per patch
// control size of input and output arrays
layout(vertices=3) out;
// input from vertex shader
in vec3 vert_coord[];
// output to evaluation shader
out vec3 vertex_coord[];

// for dynamic LOD (level of detail)
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 model;

void main()
{
    // pass attributes through
    gl_out[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position = gl_in[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position;
    vertex_coord[gl_InvocationID] = vert_coord[gl_InvocationID];


 // control tessellation
    if(gl_InvocationID==0)
    {
        // dynamic LOD (from the learnopengl.com website)
        // first: define rendering constants to control tessellation
        const float MIN_TESS_LEVEL = 4;
        const float MAX_TESS_LEVEL = 64;
        const float MIN_DISTANCE = 20;
        const float MAX_DISTANCE = 800;
        // second: transform each vertex into each eye
        vec4 eye_space_pos_1 = view * model * gl_in[0].gl_Position;
        vec4 eye_space_pos_2 = view * model * gl_in[1].gl_Position;
        vec4 eye_space_pos_3 = view * model * gl_in[2].gl_Position;
        // third: distance from camera scaled between 0 and 1
        float distance_1 = clamp((abs(eye_space_pos_1.z)-MIN_DISTANCE)/(MAX_DISTANCE-MIN_DISTANCE), 0.0, 1.0);
        float distance_2 = clamp((abs(eye_space_pos_2.z)-MIN_DISTANCE)/(MAX_DISTANCE-MIN_DISTANCE), 0.0, 1.0);
        float distance_3 = clamp((abs(eye_space_pos_3.z)-MIN_DISTANCE)/(MAX_DISTANCE-MIN_DISTANCE), 0.0, 1.0);
        // fourth: interpolate edge tessellation level based on closer vertex
        float tess_level_1 = mix(MAX_TESS_LEVEL, MIN_TESS_LEVEL, min(distance_3, distance_1));
        float tess_level_2 = mix(MAX_TESS_LEVEL, MIN_TESS_LEVEL, min(distance_1, distance_2));
        float tess_level_3 = mix(MAX_TESS_LEVEL, MIN_TESS_LEVEL, min(distance_2, distance_1));
        // fifth: set the corresponding outer tessellation levels
        gl_TessLevelOuter[0] = tess_level_1;
        gl_TessLevelOuter[1] = tess_level_2;
        gl_TessLevelOuter[2] = tess_level_3;
        // sixth: set the inner tessellation levels
        gl_TessLevelInner[0] = max(tess_level_2, tess_level_1);
        gl_TessLevelInner[1] = max(tess_level_1, tess_level_3);
    }
}

// tessellation evaluation
#version 450 core

// determines what type of tessellation to do
layout(triangles, equal_spacing, cw) in;

// input from control shader
in vec3 vertex_coord[];
// output vec
out vec3 vert;

// allows for object transformations
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    // gets barycentric coordinates from the triangles
    vec3 u = gl_TessCoord.x * vertex_coord[0];
    vec3 v = gl_TessCoord.y * vertex_coord[1];
    vec3 w = gl_TessCoord.z * vertex_coord[2];
    // makes every triangle an equal distance from the center (that's how spheres are formed)
    vec3 pos = normalize(u + v + w);

    // output tessellated shape
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(pos, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Let's try to isolate the problem by minimizing moving parts. Do you observe any difference if you remove tessellation entirely? From your screenshots, it looks like the vertices are correct, but the indices used to select which three vertices to join for each triangle are incorrect.

Comment: The first two images show what happens when tessellation is off

Comment: Then to isolate the problem, delete the rest. Solve the issue with the base mesh before you try to tessellate it. Once you get rendering of the base mesh working, if tessellation is still giving you trouble, you can post a new question just about the tessellation part.